# What does "Mark this commit" mean in gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

When using gitk, a commit can be selected in the log pane, and a right click context menu offers "Mark this commit". What does that do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the following options :

- Return to mark
- Find descendent of this and mark
- Compare with marked commit

Comment: Ah, I see, and the comment of the commit is outlined when it is marked, while the background changes when it is selected.