# How do I "unmark" a commit in gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

I mis-click "mark this commit" in gitk.

I'm glad it happened, as I'd never looked at or thought about the features it is associated with. But now that I've seen them, I'd like them to go back to being greyed out.

So I want to "unmark" the commit?

How do I do that?

Comment: It's only marked for your visit... Exit out of gitk and 're-enter' then the mark is gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option "mark this commit" ([introduced 5 years ago](http://git.kaarsemaker.net/git/commit/b9fdba7ff87d2e032df00508d06e586c17ea8216/)) is only to allow the options:

- Return to mark
- Find descendent of this and mark
- Compare with marked commit

(As seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822094/6309))

You cannot remove a mark without, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271078/how-do-i-unmark-a-commit-in-gitk/27273169#comment43012471_27271078) by [gpullen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4032517/gpullen), leaving the session.

The patch does mention:

> There is at most one marked commit at any time, and it is indicated by a box drawn around the headline.

Comment: Nice, full answer - I'm sure others will benefit from various of the additional notes in the future. Thanks!